# Can facebook application recive some data when user is removing it from his fb account?

Tags: facebook, callback

I was thinking about some callback function which facebook could call when user is removing application from his account. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Deauthorize Callback" option from the Settings > Advanced menu.

From Facebook docs:

> App Deauthorization
>
> When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the
>   app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a
>   Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we
>   will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter,
>   signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just
>   removed your app. You will not receive an user access token in this
>   request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.